# How do I let Tkinter wait for a keypress before continuing?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter

I am writing a simple GUI program in Python 2.7 using Tkinter.
The user should be prompted to "Press any button to continue".

Currently, the (simplified) code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self,root):
        Label(text="Press any key to continue!").grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.game()

    def game(self):       
        # some method to check if the user has pressed any key goes here
        Label(text="The Game is starting now!").grid(row=0,column=0)

    def key(self,event):
        print event.char
        return repr(event.char)


root = Tk() 
game_app = App(root)
root.bind('<Key>',game_app.key)
root.mainloop()
```

Do you know of an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lots of ways to do this better but here's a start.  self.state should be an enumeration so the possible states are explicitly defined, for one.

https://gist.github.com/altendky/55ddb133cb3c9624546fdf8182564f07

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self,root):
        Label(text="Press any key to continue!").grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.state = 'startup'

    def loop(self):       
        # some method to check if the user has pressed any key goes here
        if self.state == 'startup':
            Label(text="The Game is starting now!").grid(row=0,column=0)
        elif self.state == 'running':
            Label(text="The Game is running now!").grid(row=0,column=0)

        root.after(20, self.loop)

    def key(self,event):
        if self.state == 'startup':
            self.state = 'running'


root = Tk() 
game_app = App(root)
root.bind('<Key>',game_app.key)
root.after(20, game_app.loop)
root.mainloop()
```